# Searching for specific text inside balanced chars (recursive

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, perl

Given the following (sanitized)input:

```cpp
Return_t
func()
{
  Type<SubType> cursorFeature(true);

  while (nDist < 800)
  {
    Result = Example(&var, 0, cursorFeature); //interested in this because inside loop, and not dereferenced or incremented
    if (!(++cursorFeature).NoMoreRecords())
    {
      if (!BLAH(blah)
        && (otherFunc(&var, &cursorFeature->derefenced, MACRO) != 0))
      {
        bIsChanged = true;
        break;
      }
      memcpy(&var, &cursorFeature->dereferenced, sizeof(anotherType_t));
    }
  }

  //more stuff
  }
}
```

I have the following regex that captures a loop occuring after a use of `Type`

```
Type.*<.*>\s*(\w*)[^}]*?(?:while|for)\s*\(.*?\n?.*?(\{(?>[^{}]|(?-1))*\})
```

https://regex101.com/r/Kr0zQq/3

I also have the following regular expression that captures specific use of variable of type `Type`:

```
Type.*<.*>\s*(\w*)[\s\S]*?\K(?<!\+\+)\1(?!->|\+\+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Kr0zQq/4

My goal is to somehow combine these, preferably into *ONE* regex (I'd like to be able to do this search from within VS as well, if possible).  Given the nature of recursive regexes, I'm not sure this is at all possible...and I suspect it isn't.  If not, something clever that doesn't lose filename/number context when searching through hundreds of files would be awesome.  I basically need the filename and line number.  Context is great, but not required.

To clarify, I want to capture `cursorFeature` because it's of type `Type`, and then I want to search for use of it inside `"loop"{.....}`

**EDIT**

Just a note about my use of regexes to solve this problem.  The code being searched is something over a million lines, spanning multiple projects compiled by various compilers and built by multiple build systems.  And the use of both macros and advanced language features means, for example, that even VS Intellisense *often* misparses code VS is able to compile.  As does YCM (vim).  So, a perhaps overly greedy regex that is 70% false positives is fine.  (As is missing further occurences of variable use within a loop since it's generally easy to scan the rest at that point.)  However, attempting to do this as a one-liner using a "generic" PCRE was perhaps foolish. :)

Comment: I'm all ears if there's something unclear in this question.  I've tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._ -- Jamie Zawinski (attributed)

Comment: The problem here is that regex is completely the wrong tool for this task.  You need a real parser, and regex will never be able to handle all possible cases.  Even if you get it to work, it will break on other input and the person who has to maintain it, if they have any experience, will throw it out and replace it with a parser anyway.

Comment: @JimGarrison - This is a one-shot deal.  No maintenance required.  I'd obviously prefer a static analysis solution that parses C, but I'm unaware of one that could detect this particular issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "one-shot".  If it's truly "one-shot" it should be a manual operation.  If you need to apply it to multiple source files then it's not "one-shot".  Sounds like you're trying to refactor some code.  Do none of the IDE refactoring features work for you? Have you tried Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans?  The amount of time you spend getting regex to work (if that's even possible) could be spend just doing the work manually or finding a refactoring platform that does what you need.

Comment: I need to search 600,000 lines of code.  I do not need to refactor.  I need to *detect*.  Visual Studio is the IDE I have available and does not have a "detect use of a variable declared outside of a loop inside a loop" feature.

Comment: Another thought.  You don't need a full parser, just one capable of finding what you need.  Don't do it with a single regex, write Perl code to parse a line at a time, which should be MUCH easier.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Should match start from that specific name and end within a loop right after matching it?

Comment: @revo - The end goal is to detect declaration of a specific variable type outside of a loop, and then detect specific use of that variable within a following loop.  This is *likely* to cause a leak that static analysis won't detect.  Run-time detection is easy, but I need static detection.

Comment: What if you change atomic group to `(?>(?!\1)[^{}]|(?-1))*` https://regex101.com/r/0JxFyM/1?

Comment: @revo - Nailed it.  I just tacked on `\1` to the very end to make sure that's why the recursion exited.  Post as answer and I will accept.  Thank you!

Comment: You'd better avoid using greedy dot quantifiers wherever it is possible. Compare this https://regex101.com/r/fxWtAF/2 to yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three options to look if matched variable name exists in following loop or not. First one is adding `(\1)` to atomic group and check existence of this capturing group within your environment (if it's possible):

```
(?>(\1)|[^{}]|(?-2))*
```

Second, you could temper the matching process of `[^{}]` by using a negative lookahead:

```
(?>(?!\1)[^{}]|(?-1))*
```

but it fails if you don't make closing brace optional as I did in demo provided in comments.

Third and better work around is using verb `(*ACCEPT)` which causes the end of a successful match immediately without making further changes in regex:

```
(?>(\1)(*ACCEPT)|[^{}]|(?-2))*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxWtAF/1)

Comment: Thanks much.  I, unsurprisingly, got a lot of false positives, but I got a manageable set of results (a hundred or so), and found 2 resource leaks as a result.  Hardly the ideal way to detect them, but it worked :)

Comment: My pleasure. That's normal. You have to spot more cases to apply more strict rules which we can't consider by some random guesses.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a single regex requires the use of Perl code block
and a code conditional.

While the accepted answer is nice, it cannot validate the Type variable
will exist inside the balanced loops.

This code here just stores the position of the Type variable as it is
found inside all the nested loops. It doesn't miss any of them.

As an example, I've seeded the data set with multiple locations in some
loops, single location in others and none in another.

Beyond the position's in the string, how you go about locating is up to you.

Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $data = <DATA>;

my @vals;

while ( $data =~ /

          (?{ @vals = () })             # Code block - Initialize @vals

          Type .* < .* > \s* 
          ( \w+ )                       # (1)
          [^}]*? 
          (?: while | for )
          \s* \( .*? 
          (?: \r? \n )?
          .*? 

          (?<core>                      # (2 start)
               \{
               (?>
                    (?<! \+\+ )
                    ( \1 )                        # (3)
                    (?! -> | \+\+ )
                    (?{
                         # Code block - Push capture position onto @vals
                         push (@vals, pos());
                    })
                 |  [^{}] 
                 |  (?&core) 
               )*
               \}
          )                             # (2 end)

          (?(?{
               # Code conditional - Fail this block (bypass) if didn't find any
               @vals == 0
            })
               (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
          )
     /xg )
{
    print "\nfound   '$1'   at pos:   ";
    for ( @vals )
    {
        print $_ , ",  ";
    }
}

__DATA__


Return_t
func()
{
  Type<SubType> cursorFeature(true);

  while (nDist < 800)
  {
    Result1 = Example(&var, 0, cursorFeature);  
    if (!(++cursorFeature).NoMoreRecords())
    {
      if (!BLAH(blah)
        && (otherFunc(&var, &cursorFeature->derefenced, MACRO) != 0))
      {
        bIsChanged = true;
        Result2 = Example(&var, 0, cursorFeature);  
        break;
      }
      else
        Result3 = Example(&var, 0, cursorFeature);  

      memcpy(&var, &cursorFeature->dereferenced, sizeof(anotherType_t));
    }
  }

  //more stuff
  }

// ---------------------------------

Return_t
func()
{
  Type<SubType> globeFeature(true);

  while (nDist < 800)
  {
    if (!(++globeFeature).NoMoreRecords())
    {
      if (!BLAH(blah)
        && (otherFunc(&var, &penFeature->derefenced, MACRO) != 0))
      {
        bIsChanged = true;
        break;
      }
      else
      memcpy(&var, &globeFeature->dereferenced, sizeof(anotherType_t));
    }
  }
  }
} 

// ---------------------------------

Return_t
func()
{
  Type<SubType> penFeature(true);

  while (nDist < 800)
  {
    if (!(++penFeature).NoMoreRecords())
    {
      if (!BLAH(blah)
        && (otherFunc(&var, &penFeature->derefenced, MACRO) != 0))
      {
        bIsChanged = true;
        Result = Example(&var, 0, penFeature);  
        break;
      }
      else
      memcpy(&var, &penFeature->dereferenced, sizeof(anotherType_t));
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Output

```
found   'cursorFeature'   at pos:   148,  378,  465,
found   'penFeature'   at pos:   1323,
```

Comment: This answer is going to take me a bit to process.  I think the *key* feature you added was detecting multiple instances of variable usage within the loop, which I actually didn't need (my apologies, because my question did not make that clear).  I actually used the negative lookahead `\1` within the recursion followed by matching `\1` after which seemed to work in terms of guaranteeing the variable was used in the loop.  *However*, the nested negative lookahead did not work in my solution (for `++` and `->`) resulting in many false positives.

Comment: Very curious to try this out next time I run into a similar problems. I didn't even know it was possible to embed code in regexes :)

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to somehow combine these, preferably into ONE regex (I'd like to be able to do this search from within VS as well, if possible).

Here is a way to do it in the VisualStudio IDE using *Dot-Net* regex.

This will *not* produce false positives.
I think VS will span lines in the output window which will enable you to
view the blocks within the code, and across thousands of files if necessary.

I've tested this at http://regexstorm.net/tester and it works great.
Couldn't create the permalink, it said it's too long..

But you can try it yourself at regexstorm.

*(If you were to use this in a C# assembly you could get all (multiple ) the `Vars`

 found in a Loop from the capture collection:  `CaptureCollection cc = Match.Groups["Vars"].Captures;`

Then iterate through the cc.)*

This is it compressed

`Type.*<.*>\s*(\w+(?!\w))[^}]*?(?:while|for)\s*\(.*?(?:\r?\n)?.*?(?>\{(?>(?<!\+\+)(?<Vars>\1)(?!->|\+\+)|[^{}]|\{(?<Depth>)|\}(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))(?(Vars)|(?!))\})`

Readable version

```
 Type .* < .* > \s* 
 (                             # Type variable to find in Loop
      \w+ 
      (?! \w )                      # Must be an entire word
 )
 [^}]*? 
 (?: while | for )             # While or for loop
 \s* \( .*? 
 (?: \r? \n )?
 .*? 

 (?>
      \{                            # Match opening {
      (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):
           (?<! \+\+ )                   # Not incrementing variable
           (?<Vars> \1 )                 # Collect the Variable                                                                                                   
           (?! -> | \+\+ )               # Not dereferencing or incrementing variable
        |                              # or
           [^{}]                         #   Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
        |                              # or
           \{                            #  { (and increase the braces counter)
           (?<Depth> )
        |                              # or
           \}                            #  } (and decrease the braces counter).
           (?<-Depth> )
      )*                            # Repeat as needed.
      (?(Depth)                     # Condition that the braces counter is at zero.
           (?!)                          # Fail if depth > 0
      )
      (?(Vars)                      # Condition that the Variables matched something
        |  (?!)                          # Fail if Vars stack is empty
      )
      \}                            # Then match a closing }. 
 )
```

*Good Luck and let us know how this turns out !*

Comment: That works beautifully.  Easier to test quickly than the perl one since that one requires a bit (not much) of refactoring to deal with a `find | xargs` or `git ls-files | xargs` pipe.

Comment: @zzxyz - I use VS2015 ide and I've never had the need to use the dot-net regex in searches.  I'd be interested to see what the output does when it has to span lines.

Comment: I wish the search history in VS went back further so I could share some I've done.  One reason I tend to start with perl and then sometimes switch over (I can find it that way if I really need to).  I've actually done some crazy search and replaces.  But I'm a little confused by "interested to see".  Did you not test this?  Or did you test it in C#?  Anyway, the IDE just highlights/selects the whole match.

Comment: @zzxyz - This regex I tested pretty good at the online Dot-Net tester _regexstorm.com_.  I could test in C# but I'm sure it works there. The VS ide though usually output's 1 liners in the output window (a clistctrl or clistbox actually) that when you double click on takes you to the _line_ in the file. I was just wondering if when a single match block that spanned lines, all the lines are in the output window. Each match is usually prefaced with the file and line info. I'll try it next time I'm altering my commercial code (ugly MFC).

Comment: Oh, gotcha...and you'd already said that.  Yeah, "Find All" just drops you into the line that started the match and *doesn't* highlight when you double click.  "Find Next" actually works better for searches like this

Comment: clarification -- the unspoken part of "you'd already said that" was "and I forgot and asked you again".  Communication is hard.