# Regex: match everything inside closest opening and closing curly braces around expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

It's a bit hard to explain what I really want (better title suggestions are appreciated so people can find this easily in the future).

Suppose I have this:

```
{
    {
        $myTagThing$
    }
}
```

I want to match

```
{
    $myTagThing$
}
```

i.e. match everything from the last `{` before `$myTagThing$` until the first `}` after `$myTagThing$`.

So I thought I'd need this `\{.*\$myTagThing\$.*\}`, but it will also match the first `{` and last `}` in the string (i.e. the whole example). Then I tried using a lookahead and a lookbehind (both negative) `\{(.*(?!\{))\$myTagThing\$.*(?<!\})\}`(https://regex101.com/r/RfdHUH/1/). But this still doesn't work.

My theory is that I might be using lookahead and lookbehind the wrong way since this is the first time I use them.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** flags are `\gms`.

Comment: `.*` - means `any characters`. Try to use something like `[^{}]*`

Comment: After finding [guidance on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much), I have reverted question to revision 2, which was the version of the question where my answer was the accepted answer (see comments on my answer).

Comment: **Write a lexer and a parser**. It's not that hard! Not every string matching problem is well suited to regular expressions. And then you will have a device you can easily extend to match more complex languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**  *This addresses a `{ $myTagThing$ {} }` scenario no longer included in question.*

Regarding your updated question.  What you want, in .NET, is called `balanced groups`.  In other regex engines, `balanced constructs/expressions`.  The terminology slightly varies, the syntax is wildly different between engines, and so is the behavior.

Anyway, to capture the largest `{}` contents possible, you want:

```
[^{}]*
(
((?'Open'{)[^{}]*)+
((?'Close-Open'})[^{}]*)+
)*
(?(Open)(?!))
```

(Set the ignore whitespace flag or collapse this regex).  This is the core of your answer.  We just modify it with the first and last line here:

```
\{[^{}]*myTagThing
[^{}]*
(
((?'Open'{)[^{}]*)+
((?'Close-Open'})[^{}]*)+
)*
(?(Open)(?!))
[^{}]*\}
```

[regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*myTagThing%0d%0a%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%0d%0a%28%0d%0a%28%28%3f%27Open%27%7b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%2b%0d%0a%28%28%3f%27Close-Open%27%7d%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%2b%0d%0a%29*%0d%0a%28%3f%28Open%29%28%3f!%29%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%0d%0a*%5c%7d&i=%7b%0d%0a++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%24myTagThing%24%0d%0a++++++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%7d%0d%0a++++%7d%0d%0a%7d&r=&o=xsm)

The "one regex" solution can get complicated fast, but if you find yourself using .NET regexes often, you might find the following worth looking into:

[Searching for specific text inside balanced chars (recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988236/searching-for-specific-text-inside-balanced-chars-recursive)

The link above is where I had an issue where I was looking for a string like:

`Type VAR.*while{{VAR++}}` where the `while` could be followed by balanced `{}`.  The bounty-awarded answer is the one you want to look at.  It's a more complicated problem than yours, but you can see that it gets insane pretty quick:

Also see the official documentation on this feature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea these *balanced groups* existed.

Answer (score 6):

***NOTE** This was upvoted 3 times and marked as the accepted answer for [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52436040/2) of this question, before the question was changed to a different scenario, and this answer was unaccepted.*

You need to look for: opening-curly-brace, then a sequence of characters which are not open or close-curly-brace, then close-curly-brace.

Specifically: `{[^{}]*}`

Comment: I just found out that this won't work in a hierarchy. If you take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/7bhZq3/2, there aren't going to be any matches since there can't be any `{` before the closing brace. I fixed it here: https://regex101.com/r/5fPMOM/1. But then it won't count the hierarchy of braces and will match on the first closing brace it finds.

Comment: This answers my original question though (in which I didn't specify I needed hierarchy). I updated the question.

Comment: @ItsaMeTuni That isn't how StackOverflow is meant to work. You asked a question, I answered that question, which you accepted as the answer, and even commented "it works", now deleted. You then edited the question to a *completely different scenario*. If you have a different question, ask a *new* question (there is no cost!). By removing the accepted answer from my answer, you have reduced my reputation, and you make my answer look stupid, inviting further reputation damage through downvotes, since it doesn't answer the question now posed.

Comment: For reference... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much

Comment: I'm so sorry, I had no idea your reputation would get affected negatively if I removed your accepted answer. As for not writing another question and instead updating this one, I thought that someone looking for this would also want to respect the hierarchy of the brackets. My mistake again.

Comment: Indeed, the person who finds this question now might see my answer, which has been upvoted 3 times (indicating it is a good answer) and expect it to be a good answer to the new question (which it isn't) so they will downvote it. Unfortunately since zzxyz has answered the new question, been accepted and also had 3 upvotes, zzxyz's reputation would be equally affected by a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, modifying the OP's original approach:

```
\{{1}\s*\$myTagThing\$.*?\}
```

The `{1}` indicates matching the previous character exactly once. 
The `\s*` captures white space.
The `.*?` makes the search for the right brace non-greedy.

Of course if the thing is multiline you need to enable that as well.

Comment: {1} is entirely redundant, yes?  Since no {1} also indicates the same thing. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: this wouldn't work since I also need to get what's in between `{` and `$myTagThing$` and `$myTagThing$` and `}`.